# Iconv converts to utf-16 instead of utf-8

Tags: windows, encoding, unicode

I have an ISO-8859 file that I need to convert to UTF-8:

```
file *
test.csv: ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Now I use the iconv.exe for windows like this:

```
iconv.exe -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8//TRANSLIT test.csv > conv.csv
```

Problem is that now I see strange characters where latin characters (eg. à,ì,...) occur and, by checking it seems it was converted to UTF-16 instead!

```
file *
test.csv: ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
conv.csv:                        Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR line terminators
```

Why is that? How can I accomplish the simple UTF-8?

Comment: Open the result in a hex editor.  UTF-16 is a double byte encoding so you should see every other byte being a zero.  I don't think "file" is right.

Comment: Yes, but I open it on notepad++ and I see dirty characters...

Comment: When troubleshooting encoding problems you benefit a lot from being able to inspect the files at byte level.  Does the file have a BOM?  Are there zero bytes in there?

Comment: FF FE <-- I'd say it was really converted in a little endian UTF-16, I wonder why

Comment: You are the only one who can see your data, and you are not providing enough information.  I suggest you create simple example (16 bytes or so) where you also show a suitable hexdump (`od -c file` in Linux) of both input and output and add those to your question so we can see what is actually on disk.